# Customizing the_tags output?

Tags: query, tags

I am trying to display a list of tags. I want to display 6 tags but random tags. Not post tags but tags from the entire site.

```
<?php
$number_to_show = 10;
$tags = wp_tag_cloud( array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                    'format' => 'array',
                    'order' => 'RAND',
                    'number' => 0,
                    'smallest' => '10',
                    'largest' => '10',
                    'echo' => 0,
                    )
                 );

if ($tags) {
$max = ($number_to_show < sizeof($tags)) ? $number_to_show : sizeof($tags);
echo '<ul class="wp-tag-cloud">';
for ($i=0; $i < $max ; ++$i ) {
  echo "<li>{$tags[$i]}</li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

I'm not very familiar with the codex/functions but I am trying my best to understand.

I want the tags to look this this via html

```
 <a class="class-name" href="tag-permalink"> <h3>Tag Name</h3></a>
```

no `ul` or `li` list

I even tried this and it didn't work

```
<?php
$number_to_show = 6;
$tags = get_the_tags( array (
                    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                    'format' => 'array',
                    'order' => 'RAND',
                    'number' => 0,
                    'echo' => 0,
                    )
                 );

 if ($tags) {
 foreach($tags as $tag){
    echo '<a href="'.get_tag_link($tag->term_id).'" rel="tag" class="dummy-   media-object"><h3>'.$tag->name.'</h3></a>';
} ?>
```

How can i resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'post_tag',
    'hide_empty' => 0
);
$tags = get_terms( $args );
$class_name = 'my-custom-class-name';

if ( ! empty( $tags ) && ! is_wp_error( $tags ) ) {
    shuffle( $tags );   
    foreach( array_slice( $tags, 0, 6 ) as $tag ) {
        printf( '<a class="%1$s" href="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
            sanitize_html_class( $class_name ),
            get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ),
            sprintf( __( '%s') , $tag->name )
        );
    }
}
```

Since there isn't a `RAND` order option in `get_terms()` or `get_the_tags()`, what this does is:

- Get all tags from the `post_tags` taxonomy
- Shuffle  the resulting array.
- Slice the resulting array to 6 entries
- Build links with your custom class